# Why does `a.is_a? Array && !a.empty?` raise NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, short-circuiting

I'm a Python developer and I just started learning Rails, so this might be a noobish question. I found some surprising behavior in my code:

```erb
<!-- render flash message array if set -->
<% if flash[:notice].is_a? Array && !flash[:notice].empty? %>
```

This results in the following error: `` undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass ``

It seems like Ruby should not be calling `.empty?` in the second part of this clause. I confirmed that short-circuit evaluation works in other cases:

```
# this is more what I expected
[3] pry(main)> a = nil
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> !a.nil? && a.empty?
=> false
...
[6] pry(main)> a = 1
=> 1
[7] pry(main)> !a.nil? && a.empty?
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 1:Integer
from (pry):7:in `__pry__'
```

Anyone know why this behavior is happening? Seems to only trigger when I use `is_a?` and not the other operators.

Comment: As @iGian says, the error message tells us that `flash[:notice] #=> nil`. You have not told us what you think `flash[:notice]` equals, which a weakness of the question. Pay close attention to error messages. Often, as here, they pinpoint the problem.

Comment: There is no rush to select an answer. Most members wait a minimum of a couple of hours; some wait more than a day so that those asleep when the question is posted might see it before a selection is made. Another reason to wait is that sometimes, as here, it allows readers time to show you that an answer you might otherwise select is incorrect.

Comment: I selected Abdul's answer because it solved my problem, not because I was in a rush. As far as I can tell it is the most concise and correct answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because you are using space and not brackets for the parameters of `is_a?` function so rails is trying to send the whole thing as a parameter. Try it like this

```
<% if flash[:notice].is_a?(Array) && !flash[:notice].empty? %>
```

Explanation:

when you write `flash[:notice].is_a? Array && !flash[:notice].empty?` rails interpret it like `flash[:notice].is_a?(Array && !flash[:notice].empty?)` so `Array` is evaluated as `true` and `!flash[:notice].empty?` is evaluated which raises the exception.

Comment: Oh wow. So basically, you're saying my code evaluates to:

```flash[:notice].is_a?(Array && !flash[:notice].empty?)```

Is there ever any reason to omit the parentheses, then? Seems like that coding style would always have the potential of introducing subtle bugs like this.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Guess I'll just always use parentheses in complex expressions :)

Comment: Yes Exactly and as Array is a class so it evaluates to ```true``` and then rails try to evaluate ```empty?``` method which raises an error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692539/why-do-we-omit-parenthesis-only-some-of-the-time) thread might help you understand better when and when not to use parenthesis.

Comment: While that is a problem, it is not the reason the exception was raised. The error message tells us that the error occurs before `if flash[:notice].is_a? ...` is evaluated. Since we know `flash[:notice] #=> nil`, the expression simplifies to `<% if nil.is_a? Array && !nil.empty? %>`.

Comment: @ososhyong They Ruby style guide says the following about using parentheses for on method invocation: *"Use parentheses around the arguments of method invocations, especially if the first argument begins with an open parenthesis `(`, as in `f((3 + 2) + 1)`."* - [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-invocation-parens)

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I said that was a problem, but it was not the reason the exception was raised. See my comment on iGian's answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The missing parameter parentheses are the reason for the exception. By not calling `is_a?` with parentheses the content of `flash[:notice]` isn't checked to be an array which is clearly the intent if you look at the code. Due to it not being checked it can be `nil` thus resulting in the exception on the `empty?` call. So I would argue this is the reason for the exception. `flash[:notice]` being `nil` is a consequence.

Comment: @3limin4t0r and Виктор, the simple answer is that the error tells us that `empty?`'s receiver,  `flash[:notice]`, is `nil` and `nil` does not have a method `empty?`. The first step is to evaluate `flash[:notice]`. That does not raise an exception. Let `x = flash[:notice]`. Next Ruby sees if `x`  has a method `:is_a?`. It does, as do all objects. To evaluate `x.is_a?(y)` she evaluates `y = Array && !x.empty?`. Since `Array` is *truthy* and is followed by `&&` she must evaluate `x.empty?` (and then compute `!x` if no exception is raised). But an exception is raised, telling us that `x #=> nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If I understood correctly, the thing here is that the answer to  "Why does `a.is_a? Array && !a.empty?` raise NoMethodError?" is "because `a` is `nil`" . But the answer to a question like "How can I change this code to not throw an error when `a` is `nil`" would be "add parentheses around Array" or something like that. But since the second question wasn't asked, this answer is incorrect ?

Comment: @Виктор, I believe it is helpful to point out the problem with the lack of parentheses but that does not answer the question. The question, as you recounted it, is "Why does...raise `NoMethodError`".

Comment: @CarySwoveland But judging by the first comment by OP on iGian's answer and this sentence from the question: "It seems like Ruby should not be calling .empty? in the second part of this clause", the asnwer "because `a` is `nil`" seems a bit too literal. It just seems like the title of the question is badly worded but the content and the comments clearly show that he knows "`a` is `nil`" but is unsure of the reason why the second part is being executed (which this answer addresses correctly in my opinion)

Comment: I disagree with @CarySwoveland that the question should be interpreted so literally, but adding to your answer your comments explaining exactly why the exception happened would improve the answer and (I think) fix what he is objecting to.

Comment: @Wayne, how could the title of the question be more clear? Code in questions often contain multiple errors and while it's useful to point them out, job #1 is to answer the question asked.

Comment: I am surprised that this answer has so much commentary but I agree with @Виктор's answer here. My question is not literally "why am I getting an exception", but rather "why isn't short circuit evaluation working in this conditional expression?" The problem was the syntax, not the literal evaluation of ```a.nil?```.

Comment: Please do a minor edit so that I may remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `NilClass` does not respond to `empty`:

```
nil.class #=> NilClass
nil.respond_to? :empty?
#=> false
```

While it responds to `is_a?`:

```
nil.respond_to? :is_a?
#=> true
```

Shows all methods `nil` respond to:

```
nil.methods
#=> [:&, :inspect, :to_a, :to_s, :===, :to_f, :to_i, :=~, :to_h, :nil?, :to_r, :rationalize, :|, :to_c, :^, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :instance_variable_set, :protected_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :public_methods, :private_methods, :method, :public_method, :public_send, :singleton_method, :define_singleton_method, :extend, :to_enum, :enum_for, :<=>, :!~, :eql?, :respond_to?, :freeze, :object_id, :send, :display, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :yield_self, :then, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :equal?, :!, :==, :instance_exec, :!=, :instance_eval, :__id__, :__send__]
```

---

If you fix by checking first the existence of the value for the key `:notice`, as this example shows: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html, a syntax error is raised, which points to the parenthesis missing:

```
flash[:notice] && flash[:notice].is_a? Array && flash[:notice].empty?
# syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
# ...] && flash[:notice].is_a? Array && flash[:notice].empty?
#                              ^~~~~
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. My confusion stems from the fact that short-circuit evaluation isn't working as expected. If the left-hand side returns false, then the right-hand side (```is_empty?```) shouldn't be called at all.

Comment: ososhyong, suppose you had an expression `if [1,2,3].is_a?(x)...`, where `x` is an expression. To determine if  `[1,2,3].is_a?(x)` is `true` or `false` we obviously need to first evaluate `x`. Here `x` equals `Array && !flash[:notice].empty?`. Since `Array` is *truthy*, the expression reduces to  `!flash[:notice].empty?`. To evaluate that expression we first evaluate `flash[:notice].empty?`. The error message tells us that `nil` does not have a method `empty?`. So what does that tell you about `flash[:notice]`?

Comment: In my answer I stuck strictly to the question as @CarySwoveland pointed, missing the syntax error (good catch from @Abdul Rehman). I added an edit to show how it would be caught by evaluating the existence of `flash[:notice]` first.

Comment: Thanks, @iGian. Gave you an upvote since I believe you were unfairly downvoted.