# How can I fix this Ruby syntax error concerning the end keyword?

Tags: ruby, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

This is from a problem on Exercism. Making every solution so far a class method seems like an odd way of going about things but it's not my idea. Anyway here is the code:

```rb
class ResistorColorDuo
  @@colors = %w(
    black
    brown
    red
    orange
    yellow
    green
    blue
    violet
    grey
    white)

  def self.value(array)
    @@colors.index array[0] * 10 + @@colors.index array[1]
  end
end
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from resistor_color_duo_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
resistor_color_duo_test.rb:2:in `require_relative': /home/muhammad/exercism/ruby/resistor-color-duo/resistor_color_duo.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
...0]) * 10 + @@colors.index array[1]
```

I don't see the problem because the `end` keywords are all properly balanced. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: You might want to use parenthesis to ensure your code is evaluated like you expect. Eg. I think you want something like: `@@colors.index(array[0]) * 10 + @@colors.index(array[1])`

Comment: I was under the impression that parentheses were optional in this instance. Odd quirk coming from Python (and JS and nearly everything else I've ever used). But this does fix the problem. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Further to @dinjas' comment, it compiles when you change `@@colors.index array[1]` to `@@colors.index(array[1])`, but beyond that I'm not sure where you are visualizing the parentheses to be. Parentheses, even if possibly unneeded, make your code more readable, and avoid errors like this one.

Comment: @readyready15728 Parentheses are optional, but you don't want to leave them out most of the time for precedence reasons. If the statement would compile without parentheses it would be executed along the lines of `@@colors.index((array[0] * 10) + @@colors.index(array[1]))` They are mostly left out if you don't pass any arguments, or you've an otherwise clean line like `if array.include? element`

Comment: @readyready15728 - thanks. tbh, I don't think I answered that sufficiently. Would be nice if someone can explain why Ruby is expecting an `end` - it's most likely an operator precedence issue - my suspicion is that it thinks there is a block in play in that line of code. I don't have time at the moment to figure it out :)

Comment: @dinjas I believe that it's saying that it was expecting the rest of the line to be the argument to the first `index` method, after which it expected the `end` keyword, but instead it got another `index` method call with a whitespace argument. If you parenthesize the argument to the second `index` method the error goes away. Not a heck of a lot of doc on what a `tIDENTIFIER` is, but an "unexpected tIDENTIFIER" error usually comes up when leaving out a quote or paren or something. Doesn't mean the OP left out an `end`, but rather that it was looking for the `end` and encountered something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was under the impression that parentheses were optional in this instance.

Yes and no. Parentheses are indeed optional, but that doesn't mean that not using them won't change the behavior of your code, just that you won't get a syntax error.

If Ruby encounters a space immediately after a method, it will parse the rest of the line as its argument(s). So, parentheses are optional if you don't have anything on the line that isn't a part of the method argument. If you do, you have to specify what part of the line constitutes your argument list, by enclosing it in parentheses.

Here's a related potential problem to be aware of. Consider these lines, which differ by only a single space:

```
f(3+2)+1
f (3+2)+1
```

The first of these passes `5` to the function `f` and adds `1` to the result. The second one passes `6` to the function `f`. For the same reason: if Ruby encounters a space immediately after a method call, the rest of the line is parsed as the argument list.

I borrowed that example from Matz's book, where he eloquently calls this a "pernicious whitespace dependency." You have to be careful with spaces on method call lines.

This is the cause, also, of the error that you're getting. Ruby can't parse your line because you have two method calls in it. So the second one causes the error: Ruby is expecting the `end` keyword and instead it's encountering another method call.

Adding parentheses to the second one gets rid of the syntax error:

```
@@colors.index array[0] * 10 + @@colors.index(array[1])
```

But it probably doesn't give you the result you want. It will parse it like this:

```
@@colors.index(array[0] * 10 + @@colors.index(array[1]))
```

So, use parentheses for both of them. I'm not sure what you're trying to do (not sure what you want to multiply by 10), but something like this:

```
@@colors.index(array[0]) * 10 + @@colors.index(array[1])
```

In general, I prefer to parenthesize arguments to method calls. Pretty much the only time I don't use them is with `puts`, `print` and `p` (edit: and all those other ones I forgot about that Jörg has added in the comments below).

And be careful not to put a space between the method call and the open paren.

Comment: "Pretty much the only time I don't use them is with `puts`, `print` and `p`." – Standard Ruby Community Coding Style also suggests not to use parentheses for `require`, `require_relative`, `load`, `include`, `extend`, `prepend`, `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor`, and a couple of others.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're absolutely right about that. I don't use them there either! Thanks for the improvement on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to @dinjas answer from the comment section

If you have two arrays:

```
colors = [1,10]
array = [1]
```

And do something like in your example:

```
colors.index array[0] * 10
```

you will get `#=> 1` which the index of the second element of the `colors` array which is `10`. That is because Ruby will first calculate `array[0] * 10` (which is `1 * 10 = 10`) and then check for  the index of the first element that equals `10` in the `colors` array.

If you, however, add parenthesis and do this:

```
 colors.index(array[0]) * 10
```

you will get `#=> 0` because the index of the first element that equals `1` (`array[0] = 1`) in the `colors` array is `0` and `0 * 10 = 0`.

There was also a similar issue a few days ago, you might want to check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052299/9785060).